# Django User Management: Gets a 404 page | can't logout using "localhost:8000/accounts/logout

Tags: django, authentication, django-views, django-urls

I used an online instractions for building my first application on Django. I created a project and an app and it's all works fine by now. The problem is, whenever I want to log in, it redirect to "accounts/login" and I log in using my username and password
and i cannot log out while i'm clicking on the button i added to log out its redirecting to a build-in accounts/logout and it doesnt exist.
I added this in my app urls:

```
path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
```

Where did I go wrong?

I tried

```
path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
```

Comment: are you using default django's User Or did you use CustomUser?

Comment: explain me more. I added supersuers and users in the admin section

Comment: meaning you didn't do it programmatically?